# error while using mvn clean package "parent.artifactId" must be changed, the parent element cannot have the same groupId:artifactId as the project

Tags: java, maven

Hi can anyone help me to resolve the issue which am geeting while using "mvn clean package" command

[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[WARNING] expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ... be the preferred\r\n   | server for that repository.\r\n   |-->\r\n  <m... @152:5)  @ maven-3.8.6-bin\apache-maven-3.8.6\conf\settings.xml, line 152, column 5
[WARNING]
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] 'parent.artifactId' must be changed, the parent element cannot have the same groupId:artifactId as the project. @ line 7, column 17

The project com.tibco.xpd.core:com.tibco.xpd.core.feature:4.0.3000-SNAPSHOT BW\product\com.tibco.xpd.core.feature\features\com.tibco.xpd.core.feature\pom.xml) has 1 error

```
 'parent.artifactId' must be changed, the parent element cannot have the same groupId:artifactId as the project. @ line 7, column 17
```

To see the full stack trace of the fatels, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

For more information about the fatels and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [Help 1] [http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingExceptio`](http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingExceptio%60)

- List item

Comment: In my pom both group ID and artifact id is same.. but am not able to change artifact ID. is there any way i can do it ? as my build is success but getting issue while packing.

Comment: Your pom.xml is invalid.  Fix that first.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen can you please guide in what i need to fix in pom.xml file?

Comment: Make sure it is valid xml first. The xml parser complains about something.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xpd.core.feature</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.xpd.core.feature</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

Comment: <modules>
    <module>features/com.xpd.core.feature</module>
    <module>features/com.xpd.core.feature.devdocs</module>
    <module>plugins/com.xpd.core.ant.task</module>
    <module>plugins/com.xpd.core.branding</module>
  </modules>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen above is my pom.xml file. how check if its valid or not. Also am not able to change artifactID in the pom file as both groupID and ArtifactID is same. Is there any way we can do it ?